# How do I get "new" behavior in python?

Tags: python, list, new-operator

How do I do the following in python?

```
a = ['foo']
b = a
b.append('bar')

print(a) # ['foo']
print(b) # ['foo', 'bar']
```

I essentially need the behavior of "new" in other keywords

Comment: you just need to make a copy of a instead of "b" being a reference to the object pointed to by a. try `b = a.copy()`

Comment: also, read this. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html